# How to do a search by UPC?

Tags: deezer

I've looked into the documentation, but have yet to see how can I do a search based on UPC.

I can see what I get it from each album, but how to do the lookup?

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the format for UPC album lookups: http://api.deezer.com/album/upc:093046516024