# Ean OR UPC Deezer

Tags: deezer

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to recover an album on deezer by his ean or upc?I currently retrieve the JSON from the album but nothing concerning this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a search by UPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914112/how-to-do-a-search-by-upc)

Answer (score 5):

You can perform a query on Deezer's api using the following url :

```
https://api.deezer.com/album/upc:3700368403150
```

Comment: Excellent you is my savior